# Biblical Speeddating (Matching/Scheduling/Optimization)

Tags: algorithm, search, mathematical-optimization, constraint-satisfaction, stable-marriage

Imagine it's 3000 BCE and we're setting up some heteronormative, polygamous speeddating.
There are `n_c` men and `n_s` women (`n_s > n_c`).
The speeddating will proceed in `n_r` rounds.
In each round, each of the men will meet with a woman.
So `n_r*n_c` slots to fill.

Also, they've all filled out stone tablet questionnaires from which we've constructed a scoring function, 
`u(i,j)`, 
which gives the utility of pairing man `i` with woman `j` in one of the slots.

The goal is to maximize the sum of scores over all slots, under the constraint 
that no man meets the same woman more than once and 
that each woman meet with at most 
`ceil(n_r*n_c/n_s)` 
men.
(Which is to say each woman should meet with about the same number of men.)

---

Can you sketch an algorithm to solve this? Number of men and women can be assumed to be under 100, probably under 50. Oh and assume we brought modern hardware with us to 3000 BCE.

Answer (score 1):

Can be formulated as a min-cost circulation problem, then solved using one of the many algorithms for that (e.g., cycle canceling, network simplex; these polynomial-time algorithms should be very fast for 50 elements).

Make a vertex for each man and woman. Make a source/sink vertex. The men have arcs from the source/sink with minimum flow `n_c` and capacity `n_c` and cost zero. The women have arcs to the source/sink of capacity `ceil(n_r*n_c/n_s)` and cost zero. For each man and woman, there is a capacity `1` arc from the man to the woman. The cost of this arc is `-u(i,j)`, where the man is `i` and the woman is `j`.

Now we have to schedule things. The idea is repeatedly construct a male-female bipartite matching (i.e., single-round schedule) that matches all of the women who need to be scheduled this round. Those are the women whose degree equals the men. By an averaging argument (if the male degree is k, then n women of degree k must neighbor at least n men, since otherwise some man would have degree greater than k), Hall's theorem applies, and we can perfectly match these women. By a similar argument over men, we can repeatedly augment this matching to match all men. Delete all of the matching edges and repeat.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to maximize the score, that assumes you'll be evaluating the questionnaires between rounds. This begins to sound like a fairly standard clustering problem.

Start with at least two rounds of randomly assigning men and women, being sure not to create any duplicate pairings. At that point, you should have at least two men who have met with the same woman.

Then you can use the typical "if Jim and Joe both like oranges, and Joe also likes lemons, then Jim is likely to like lemons."

If I were to approach this problem, the first technique I'd try would be [cosine similarity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity). That *should* give you a much higher total score than randomly assigning pairs.

My first pass at the problem would just use total score to determine similarity. That is, I would compare the total scores of Man A and Man B evaluating the same woman. That's simple to implement because it involves only one dimension. Once I'd proven that works and does indeed give a better score than random assignment, I'd probably extend the number of dimensions by comparing on a per-question basis. After all, although A and B might both give woman Z the same score, one might be focused on physical attributes and the other on things like personality and intelligence, with no thought to physical attributes. Extending to multiple dimensions is more complex, true, but it should improve the scores markedly.

Comment: Sorry, clarification: the questionnaires are all ahead of time. Ie, there's just a static utility function for the value of every pairing. No collaborative filtering aspect, though I like the way you think!

Answer (score 0):

We just found this paper:

http://i11www.iti.uni-karlsruhe.de/_media/teaching/theses/sa-strasser-10.pdf

Which attacks exactly this problem.

(I'm amused that they seem to be solving the speeddating problem for real. My formulation, if you couldn't tell, was just made up as something isomorphic to the actual problem we're solving.)